Catch SIGINT during an early rubygems startup
Is there a way to catch SIGINT during an early rubygems startup?
I have a bash script that creates many Ruby child processes, and when I hit Ctrl-C, those children almost always dump a backtrace that has no relation to my code.
This can be simulated by the following one-liner:
$ while true; do ruby -e 'trap("INT") { exit 11 }'; echo $?; done
0
0
^C<internal:dir>:412:in `glob': Interrupt
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/util.rb:104:in `glob_files_in_dir'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:776:in `block in each_gemspec'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:775:in `each'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:775:in `each_gemspec'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:787:in `each_spec'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:841:in `load_defaults'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems.rb:1374:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `require'
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
1
0
0
^C/home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems.rb:1219:in `sub': Interrupt
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems.rb:1219:in `block in register_default_spec'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems.rb:1210:in `each'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems.rb:1210:in `register_default_spec'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:844:in `block in load_defaults'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:789:in `block in each_spec'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:777:in `block (2 levels) in each_gemspec'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:776:in `each'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:776:in `block in each_gemspec'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:775:in `each'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:775:in `each_gemspec'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:787:in `each_spec'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:841:in `load_defaults'
        from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems.rb:1374:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `require'
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
1
0
^C

Here I quickly pressed Ctrl-C 3 times.

You could pass --disable-gems to the ruby executable in order to not load any gems. This way, your script starts immediately and can register the signal handler much earlier. However, might have to require needed gems yourself.

#!/usr/bin/env -S ruby --disable-gems

trap('SIGINT') { exit 100 }

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
...

I still get occasional internal:ast:58:in singleton_method_added': Interrupt, or similar, though.
